# Navbar hover effect no longer works when I insert a image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a navbar inside a header tag. the header tag is flex. the navbar too. in the navbar i have three a tags with the display value inline-block; and a padding in the height and width. So far so good. When i hover the links the hover effect is shown over the whole height.

**The problem:** If I add an image to the first link, I can't make the image higher than 10 px because the padding affects the entire navbar height. What I do not want.

**Question:** How can I add the image to the link without it affecting the height of the navbar?

**My code**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
} 

header {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: green;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:100%;
}

.logo {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar a:not(:first-child) {
 display: inline-block;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.flex {
  gap:10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 180px;
  color: color;
  height:50vh;
  background: black;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/40">Logo
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar">  
      <a href="#home">
        
        <div class="flex">
          <div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30">
          </div>
          <div>10000</div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>    
    </nav>    
  </header>

  <main class="main">
    text
  </main>
</div>
```

**expected**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  pading: 0;
} 

header {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: green;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:100%;
}

.logo {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar a:not(:first-child) {
 display: inline-block;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.flex {
  gap:10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 180px; /* Add a top margin to avoid content overlay */
  color: color;
  height:50vh;
  background: black;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/40">Logo
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar">  
      <a href="#home">
        10000
      </a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>    
    </nav>    
  </header>

  <main class="main">
    xca
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use `flex` behavior to align and stretch instead of additional markups

In the code snippet below, I removed the extra markup in the first `a` element that contains the `img`. Instead, I made all `a` tags `display: inline-flex` and removed vertical padding in the first one. Then, using the parent `nav` element's `align-items` property, I ensured each `a` tag has the same full height for consistent hover effect.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
} 

header {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: green;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:100%;
}

.logo {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.navbar a {
 display: inline-flex;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.navbar a:first-of-type {
  padding-top:0;
  padding-bottom:0;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.flex {
  gap:10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 180px;
  color: color;
  height:50vh;
  background: black;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/40">Logo
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar">  
      <a href="#home">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30">
        10000
      </a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>    
    </nav>    
  </header>

  <main class="main">
    text
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Bumhan Yu! Thank you for your good answer and explanation! Have a nice day :-)